# Proof that holomorphic functions from $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ to $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ are the rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that

> If $f:\mathbb{C}_\infty \to \mathbb{C}_\infty$ is holomorphic, then there exists polynomials $P$ and $Q$ such that $f(z) = \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}_\infty$

What I want to use is that a meromorphic function in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ is a meromorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$ who is holomorphic at $\infty$ or have a pole at $\infty$. So, holomorphic functions from $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ are meromorphic functions in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ because they are holomorphic at $\infty$.

Now, I know from Stein's Complex Analysis book that:

> $\textbf{Theorem 3.4} \,$The meromorphic functions in the extended complex plane
> are the rational functions.

So this theorem implies that holomorphic function in extended complex plane are rational functions.

Is ok to use this to prove my first statement?

$\textbf{Edit:}$
And.. I have a feeling that converse isn't true because if we have rational function in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ we have that it is meromorphic function and can have poles. If we restrict the domain to $\mathbb{C}_\infty - \{z \in \mathbb{C}_\infty : z \text{ is pole for} f\}$ then we obtain a holomorphic function? Are these 2 statements also true?

Comment: Partially... but I want to know if my method is ok (I've added an edit with 2 more questions)

Comment: 1. The sentence, "So, holomorphic functions from $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ are meromorphic functions in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ because they are holomorphic at $\infty$." is not correct: A meromorphic function on the sphere can have a pole at $\infty$. <> 2. A meromorphic function on the sphere may be viewed as a _holomorphic_ [sic] map to the sphere. This fact appears related to [another of your questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4793438/when-a-function-is-holomorphic-on-extended-complex-plane). <> 3. Please ask only one question per post. ;)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang at 1. : Yes. A meromorphic function can have a pole at $\infty$ or not. So holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}_\infty$, because don't have poles at $\infty$, aren't they meromorphic functions?